# Remove closest uploaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, closest

I am searching for hours now for this simple answer. I have 5 upload fields for images and I want to make a delete button for each uploaded image. If you click on this button the closest image needs to be removed.

I know there are lots of questions on Stack about this item, but cannot find the right one. I have tried `closest()`, `find()`, `closest()` with `children()` but cannot make it work.

Can someone give me the right hint?

I made a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4SHUG/

This is my html:

```
<div class="stn_uploader">
    <p class="delete">Delete</p>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hME1fzYTKkc/Tl157uRJ3gI/AAAAAAAAIzQ/OnqAvShZaLA/s1600/white-clouds.jpg" width="300"/>

</div>

<div class="stn_uploader">
    <p class="delete">Delete</p>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hME1fzYTKkc/Tl157uRJ3gI/AAAAAAAAIzQ/OnqAvShZaLA/s1600/white-clouds.jpg" width="300"/>

</div>

<div class="stn_uploader">
    <p class="delete">Delete</p>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hME1fzYTKkc/Tl157uRJ3gI/AAAAAAAAIzQ/OnqAvShZaLA/s1600/white-clouds.jpg" width="300"/>

</div>
```

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
          $(this).closest('.img').remove();  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image is sibling thus `closest()` will not work. You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
          $(this).next('img').remove();  
    });
});
```

***OR***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
          $(this).closest('.stn_uploader').find('img').remove();  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! next doesn't work, but .closest() .find() does!

Comment: Yeah is see. But I have tried it in the same jsfiddle and didn't work. But now it does!

Answer (score 1):

img is a sibling, closest looks at itself and its ancestors. The second issue is your selecotr is wrong, you are looking for a class "img" and not an element "img"

You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next().remove();
```

or [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).siblings("img").remove();
```

or if you want to delete the entire block, closest would work.

```
$(this).closest('.stn_uploader').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` traverse up the DOM tree and get the first matched ancestor.

In your case, `img` is the next element of your paragraph. So you need to use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
      $(this).next().remove();  // or $(this).siblings('.img').remove();
});
```

Btw, your images don't have any class named as `img`, if you want to target `<img>` tag, you can use:

```
$('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('img').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using (".img").There are no class in img tag.Try This code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {

          $(this).next('img').remove();  
    });

});
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {

              $(this).parent('.stn_uploader').remove();  
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not far away ;)

```
$('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.img').remove();  
});
```

First, you're using a class `.img` instead of the element node name `img`.

Then, `img` is a sibling not a parent element, so if you wanted to find it from `.delete` you should use [next](http://api.jquery.com/next) :

```
$('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
    $(this).next('img').remove();  
});
```

I think you should also look at this option to remove the whole container :

```
$('.stn_uploader .delete').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();  
});
```